# are these structure "It's adj for somebody to do something" / "It's adj of somebody to do something" generic ones?

Tags: grammar

I am non-native English speaker and my English teachers often teach these structures to me

"**It's adj for somebody to do something**". Ex: *It is necessary for you to get up early*

"**It's adj of somebody to do something**". Ex: *It was really kind of you to help me.*

My question is that:

Can we apply these structures for all adjectives?

If "**yes**", then are *It is good for you to get up early* & *It is good of you to get up early*  interchanged?

If "**no**", then when is to use the 1st & when is to use the last?

Seem not many websites mention this!!

Comment: "Can we apply these structures for all adjectives?" No, not really. I'd say it probably comes down to idiom—which you'd have to check for each word, if you don't already know.

Comment: It seems to be a different question, but the two examples you give have completely different meanings. The first is something your parent might tell you, as in "It is good for you [healthy, in this case] to eat vegetables," the second is praising the person for getting up early (I mostly hear this construction used sarcastically, but it's not sarcastic if you use "kind").

Comment: @ralph.m, can I say "*it is great for all of us to be here*". And if you check the word "*great*" in the dictionary, then you won't see any "*it is great for somebody to do something*"

Comment: `can I say "it is great for all of us to be here".` Yes, you can, although it has a particular meaning: "It benefits us in some way to be here." What you are probably trying to say is: "It is great *that we are all here*"—or, in other words, "it's really great that you've all come" etc.

Comment: Look up the grammar book. That's what it is for.

Comment: @Rathony, can you give me a link that discuss about this structure "**It's adj for somebody to do something**"

Comment: I din't mention anything about a link. A grammar book has it covered.